# What does the "NS" prefix to a class name mean in iOS?

Tags: ios

I notice the "NS" prefix in all the class names in iOS. What does that mean? (e.g NSMutableArray)

Comment: May I introduce you to our "parent" site Stack Overflow where everyone who programs iOS hangs out and talks about developing, developer tools and things like how best to comment code, name classes, and all manner of programming history. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473758/what-does-the-ns-prefix-mean

Comment: Unless there is some direct tie in to how users use Apple products (and please edit in and vote to re-open this) I'll close this as being a development question not relating to terminal, AppleScript or Automator per the [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 16):

It stands for [NextSTEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nextstep), the operating system that Steve Jobs (caused to be) built after he was evicted from Apple.  Objective-C and the NextSTEP API are the basis of the newer OpenSTEP and MacOS-X APIs.

Answer (score 1):

It is an acronym for either NeXTSTEP or NeXT-Sun - both dating back to the origins of the Cocoa API.

Comment: Definitely not NeXT-Sun NS predates any NeXT Sun tie up. The result of the tie up was OpenStep